# how to load balance gRPC java client requests over NLB

Tags: java, grpc, nlb

I am testing gRPC java client to its server over aws NLB load balancing but all traffics hit the same node. I try to understand how it would work over NLB.

As gRPC is using persistent TCP connection, I assume its client would establish multiple tcp connections over NLB to its server and randomly serve requests to those connections?

I am using the code from grpc.java example

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(endPoint, port).usePlaintext().build();
GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub blockingStub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
response = blockingStub.sayHello(request);
```

I saw some docs said ManagedChannel encapsulates the complexity of connection pool and I suppose it will maintain connections and decide which connection to use?

Since stub is thread safe, I guess I could reuse the same stub for all requests?

So the problem is how I could make requests load balanced cross every server node. I ran the example over NLB but all requests hit the same node with no luck.

Comment: Just found lb blog from grpc. https://grpc.io/blog/loadbalancing. So looks like client side lb need extra implementation. Saw many articles claim grpc would work with and NLB, still don't know how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

NLB can't load balance grpc properly. It's an inefficient hack.

grpc provides thick client side load balance solution for trusted client. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md